# How to force two "blocks" to be on the same page, without minipage?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, titlesec

I have the following situation (what follows is pseudo-code):

```
\mySection*{Title}

\begin{mdframed-theorem}
   Bla bla [...] that is long.
\end{mdframed-theorem}

Then something else, the starting of new paragraph, etc.
```

The problem I am facing is that `Title` is printed at the bottom of page 1 but the theorem is printed at the top of page 2.

I am looking for a mechanism to force `Title` and what immediately follows to be on the same page. Starting a new page before `\mySection{...}` is not at all to be avoided, it is not a problem for me. But, having the `Title` on a page and what follows on the next one is to be avoided.

How can I do? (I can put whatever I want in `\mySection*`, I don't want necessarily to use `\section*`)

PS: I don't think it is related to `mdframed`. I don't want to use `minipage` since I am looking for an automatic solution.

---

### edit: more details

- `\begin{mdframed-theorem}` stands for `\begin{xxxx}` where `xxxx` is defined with `\mdtheorem` (of `mdframed`).
- anything is acceptable in `\mySection{}` !!! (actually, I use a non-starred version. I put a star just to imply that my sections are not numbered).

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful here. What defines the `mdframed-theorem` environment, and what's an acceptable definition for `\mySection*` if you don't want to use `\section*`?

Comment: I would be difficult to give a MWE. I am more looking for hints about how to use penalties or "glue" so that these two "blocks" will be on the same page, whatever comes.

Comment: Can't reproduce with an article, a `\section*`, and a `quote` environment. If there's enough room to fit two lines of the quote on the initial page, it and the section header stay together there. If there's less room than that, both the section header and the quote move to the next page. So there's something different between my attempt at a MWE and what you actually have.

Comment: you need to use `needspace` package or the idea behind.

Comment: Hi @touhami, it worked. Thanks. You can make it an answer. I just did
`\newcommand{\mySection}[1]{\needspace{3cm}\section*{#1}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use `\needspace{<length>}` command from [needspace](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/needspace) package.

```
\newcommand{\mySection}[1]{\needspace{3cm}\section*{#1}}
```